# Standalone format reader

Tags: support, markdown

I keep a saved copy of my question while typing it, especially if it is long and editing it takes time.

Is there a "standalone Stack Exchange format reader" or WYSIWYG editor to view/edit it from a saved file directly?

Comment: Any stand alone markdown editor should do.

Comment: I did some research and found [this list](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=markdown+text-editors) for you.

Answer (score 6):

Stack Exchange is using an open source editor, called "pagedown", which [is available on GitHub](https://github.com/omegaup/pagedown).

You can download the whole ZIP file, extract, and you will get a folder called "demo" with a file called *demo.html* - you can work locally with that file, store the raw markdown and post on your free time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [stackedit.io](https://stackedit.io/) which will render a superset of Stack Exchange Markdown and includes MathJax support. Files can be saved to local browser storage or to the Cloud -- which can allow others to collaborate on them.